Monolog buffer explanation
Can someone explain what is buffer_size, stop_buffering, and passthru_level configuration options are in Monolog? Does buffer size mean that logs will not be written in real life but cached and sent all at once after N messages or after request execution?
I have an issue in that I do not see logs for requests that are hitting request_terminate_timeout amount of time, and returning with 504 status, and I'm wondering if it could be because of some issues with logs buffering.

Monolog Buffering Settings

buffer_size: This tells Monolog how many log messages to store in memory before writing them to a file or another logging destination. For example, if buffer_size is set to 10, Monolog will wait until it has 10 messages before saving them.

stop_buffering: This setting controls whether Monolog should stop storing messages in memory after the first batch of messages is written out. If set to true, Monolog will immediately write out each new message after the initial batch. If set to false, it will continue storing messages in memory until the buffer is full again.

passthru_level: This setting specifies a level of importance for messages that should not be stored in memory but written out immediately. For example, if set to ERROR, any message of ERROR level or higher will be written out right away, bypassing the buffer.


Your Logging Issue
You're not seeing logs for requests that hit the request_terminate_timeout limit and return a 504 status. This might be because the logs are being stored in memory and not written out before the request times out. When the script is killed by the timeout, any messages still in the buffer are lost.
How to Fix It

Direct Logging for Important Messages: Configure Monolog to write important messages immediately, bypassing the buffer. Set passthru_level to a level like ERROR to ensure these messages are logged right away.

Reduce Buffer Size: Make the buffer smaller so that messages are written out more frequently. For example, if you set buffer_size to 1, every message will be written out as soon as it’s logged.

Disable Buffering: If you don’t need buffering, you can disable it altogether. This ensures every log message is written out immediately.


Example Configuration
Here's an example of how you can set this up:
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\BufferHandler;

$streamHandler = new StreamHandler('/path/to/your.log', Logger::DEBUG);
$bufferHandler = new BufferHandler($streamHandler, 10, Logger::DEBUG, true, true, Logger::ERROR);

$logger = new Logger('name');
$logger->pushHandler($bufferHandler);

// Your application code

In this setup:

buffer_size is 10, so messages are stored until there are 10 of them.
stop_buffering is true, so after the first batch of messages, new messages are written out immediately.
passthru_level is ERROR, so ERROR and CRITICAL messages are never stored in memory but written out right away.

If you prefer no buffering, you can configure it like this:
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$streamHandler = new StreamHandler('/path/to/your.log', Logger::DEBUG);

$logger = new Logger('name');
$logger->pushHandler($streamHandler);

// Your application code

This ensures all messages are logged immediately without being stored in memory.
By tweaking these settings, you can make sure your log messages are written out even if a request times out.

Did you get this from chatGPT or another AI tool? It reads like that kind of content. If so, please be aware that answering with AI-generated content is specifically banned on Stackoverflow - see Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable. You must at least understand what the AI gave you, and tailor it to the specific question, before posting
